# Python Regex some name + US Address

Tags: regex, street-address

I have these kind of strings:

```
WILLIAM SMITH 2345 GLENDALE DR RM 245 ATLANTA GA 30328-3474
LINDSAY SCARPITTA 655 W GRACE ST APT 418 CHICAGO IL 60613-4046
```

I want to make sure that strings I will get are like those strings like above.
Here's my regular expression:

```
[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ [0-9]{3,4} [A-Z]+ [A-Z]{2,4} [A-Z]{2,4} [0-9]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$
```

But my regular expression only matches the first example and does not match the second one.

Comment: You are need to also check for the 'W' before 'GRACE'.  You can add optional `(?:\w )?` for that.  `[A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ [0-9]{3,4} (?:\w )?[A-Z]+ [A-Z]{2,4} [A-Z]{2,4} [0-9]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z]{2} [0-9]{5}-[0-9]{4}$`  or `(?:[A-Z] )?`

Comment: Thanks. Please let me test it with other samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's dawg's regex with capturing groups:

```
^([A-Z]+[ \t]+[A-Z]+)[ \t]+(\d+)[ \t](.*)[ \t]+([A-Z]{2})[ \t]+(\d{5}(?:-\d{4}))$
```

Here's the [url](https://regex101.com/r/pwppw3/1).

**UPDATE**

sorry, I forgot to remove non-capturing group at the end of dawg's regex...
Here's new regex without non-capturing group: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fElcCG/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[A-Z]+[ \t]+[A-Z]+[ \t]+\d+.*[ \t]+[A-Z]{2}[ \t]+\d{5}(?:-\d{4})$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dR2GpU/1/)

Explanation:

```
1. ^[A-Z]+[ \t]+[A-Z]+[ \t]+  Starting at the start of line, 
    two blocks of A-Z for the name 
    (however, names are often more complicated...)

2. \d+.*[ \t]+[A-Z]{2}[ \t]+  Using number start and 
   two letter state code at the end for the full address
   Cities can have spaces such as 'Miami Beach'

3. \d{5}(?:-\d{4})$  Zip code with optional -NNNN with end anchor
```

Comment: However, your regex does work when there's no +4 digit at the end.

Comment: Thank you, @dawg, for your answer! It helped me a lot.